# React redirect from a route to another route and pass the id to the new one

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

In short words, I want to know why this line does not work:

```
<Route path="/game/prepare/:id" element={ <Redirect to="/game/live/:id" /> } />
```

More description:

I have this url: `www.mysite.com/game/prepare/1234` and I want it to instantly redirect to `www.mysite.com/game/live/1234`.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation doesn't work because you are redirecting to the literal path string `"/game/live/:id"`, the original `id` path parameter value is dropped. `Redirect` also ins't a valid `react-router-dom@6` component. You should use the `Navigate` component, which is the spiritual successor to the RRDv5 `Redirect` component.

```
<Route
  path="/game/prepare/:id"
  element={<Redirect to="/game/live/:id" />}
/>
```

You'll need to create a custom component that can read the current route path params and render the appropriate redirection.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const RedirectToLiveGame = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return <Navigate to={`/game/live/${id}`} replace />;
};
```

```
<Route
  path="/game/prepare/:id"
  element={<RedirectToLiveGame />}
/>
```